# TVirtualStringTree is displaying incorrect data i.e displaying "node" in each cell. How to display correct data?

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I followed the conventional  practice of displaying data on TVirtualStringTree. But it displays only the string "node" in each cell. Can someone tell what I am missing here ?
Thanks in advance.

**My Code:**

```
type
  TRecFileDirectory = record
    FileDirectory: WideString;
    FileDirectoryLock: wordbool;
  end;

  TPRecFileDirectory = ^TRecFileDirectory;

implementation

procedure TForm2.btn4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  NewNode: PVirtualNode;
  ptrFileDir: TPRecFileDirectory;
begin
  vsTree1.BeginUpdate;
  for I := 0 to Length(arrFileDirectory)-1 do
  begin
    NewNode := vsTree1.AddChild(nil);
    ptrFileDir := vsTree1.GetNodeData(NewNode);
    ptrFileDir^.FileDirectory := arrFileDirectory[I].FileDirectory;
    ptrFileDir^.FileDirectoryLock := arrFileDirectory[I].FileDirectoryLock;
  end;
  vsTree1.EndUpdate;
  btn4.caption := btn4.caption+' DONE';
end;
```

[image: The VirtualStringTree shows data like this]

Comment: Where is your code that tells the tree how to render the contents of each node's `TRecFileDirectory`? It is not enough to just store your custom data inside each node, you have to tell the tree how to display it, too. That is the whole point of a "virtual" UI control.

Comment: thank you. I got the point. Could you please provide any code snippet or link which will demonstrate how to tell tree to display data ?

Comment: I think you are explaining about OnGetText in which mapping of customdata to the grid will be done. I tried it and it is working partly. Throwing some AV but I see it is because of other reasons. Anyway, Thank you.

Comment: "*I think you are explaining about OnGetText*"- yes. I didn't know the exact name, I'm not a VST user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement an event handler for the `OnGetText` event, that extracts the string to be displayed from your data, dependant on the column and node that is supplied. For example:

```
procedure TForm1.VSTGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
var
  MyData: TPRecFileDirectory;
begin
  MyData := Node.GetData();
  if Column = 0 then
    CellText := MyData.FileDirectory; 
end;
```

Answer (score -3):

Set `DefaultText` property to empty string, e.g. in code or in Inspector

Comment: Tx for the response.
Tried with DefaultText setting to Empty string but no luck :(

Comment: DefaultText property controls what text to display in case OnGetText event is not handled. So if you want to display something else, handle OnGetText event.

Comment: Oh ok, OnGetText event code is implemented and it is working partly now. Thank you for the help.
Still OnGetText throwing some AVs because of the data. Now, My VST has 3 columns of datatype string and my record has 3 string var. I am unsure why is it throwing AV.

Comment: You should also handle OnGetNodeDataSize event and return something like: NodeDataSize := SizeOf(TPRecFileDirectory);
Or set NodeDataSize property of the tree view.